# Retrieving only a section of a HTML file using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

I'm using the `file_get_contents()` function in PHP to retrieve a remote webpage and run it into my table parsing script. But basically, my table parsing script only takes the first table on the page.

The page I'm trying to download has 3 html tables in it, so I was wondering if there was a way of only taking the third table? Most likely I'd want to only take lines 30 to 60 in the HTML file. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no file downloading command that will parse a HTML file for you, and determine the exact chunk that needs to be downloaded. I don't think there is a way around downloading the whole thing, and using a [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662) to fetch the table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your main file up into three separate files (once for each table) which just get 'included' into the original.

Then you will just need to do a `file_get_contents` for the table that you want.

**Edit**

As an example, consider this file:

```
 <h1>I am a header</h1>
 <table id = 'table1>
 ...
 </table>

 <table id = 'table2'>
 ...
 </table>

 <table id = 'table3'>
 ...
 </table>
```

And compare it with this file:

```
<h1>I am a header</h1> 
<?php
    include 'table1.php';
    include 'table2.php';
    include 'table3.php'; 
?>
```

`table1.php` will simply hold everything between the table tags for table 1, and similarly for `table2.php` and `table3.php`.

If you want table 3, perform your `file_get_contents` on `table3.php`

Comment: I don't want the first 2 tables though

Comment: If they're in separate files, you can get whichever one you want.

Comment: How would I split them up into different files?

Comment: How do I split them each into their individual files?

Comment: Just copy and paste everything between `<table>` and `</table>` into a new file, then save it.

Comment: But I want to do this automatically in PHP, because the content I'm downloading is dynamic

Comment: You can make it dynamic, I'm not sure what the issue is.  The separate files are also PHP files, which will be processed before being sent out to the client.